# Changing a user's password

Tags: php, classes

I wrote this class for the project I'm currently working on. It's basically used to change a user's password. I'd like to know your thoughts on the basic structure/design of this class and how it can be improved, or if you'd have written it differently.

```
class Recover_password{
    //class by sami
    private $conn;
    private $password_one;
    private $password_two;

    function initialize_connection($conn){
        if($conn instanceof PDO){
            $this->conn = $conn;
        }else{
            echo "Connection problem accured";
        }
    }

    function is_posted(){
        if(isset($_POST["change_password"])){
            $this->is_empty();
        }else{
            echo "nothing's being posted!";
        }
    }

    private function is_empty(){
        foreach($_POST as $post_value){
            if(!empty($post_value)){
                $is_empty = false;
            }else{
                echo "Field/s are empty";
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isset($is_empty)){
            $this->set_values();
        }
    }

    private function set_values(){
        $this->password_one = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST["password_two"], '"')));
        $this->password_two = strip_tags(stripslashes(trim($_POST["password_one"], '"')));

        if($this->password_one == $this->password_two){
            if( (strlen($this->password_one) > 10) or (strlen($this->password_two) > 10) ){
                $this->password_one = md5($this->password_one);
                $this->change_password_to_new();
            }else{
                $this->show_message("The password you provided is too weak");
            }
        }else{
            $this->show_message("Please make sure the passwords match");
        }
    }

    private function change_password_to_new(){
        $insert_pass_query = $this->conn->prepare("update registered_users set user_password = :user_password where username = :username");
        if( $insert_pass_query->execute(array('user_password'=>$this->password_one, 'username'=>$_SESSION["logged_in"])) ){
            $this->show_message("Password has been sucessfully changed!");  
        }else{
            $this->show_message("Unknown error occured, please contact admin.");
        }
    }

    private function show_message($message){
        $_SESSION["message"] = $message;
        header("location: show_message.php");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**basic structure/design**

I would not echo in a class, but throw an exception instead. That way, the calling class can decide how to handle these problems, and your class will thus be more flexible.

Your class also does two things: It changes a password, and it redirects. I would leave the redirection to the calling class as well (but this is probably a matter of taste).

**`is_empty`**

The `is_empty` function doesn't seem to be working correctly.

If only one of the two fields is filled in by the user, `Field/s are empty` is echoed, but `set_values` is called anyways.

In this case it doesn't really matter, because it will not do anything. But then your function could be simplified to:

```
private function is_empty(){
    foreach($_POST as $post_value){
        if(empty($post_value)){
            echo "Field/s are empty";
            break;
        }
    }

    $this->set_values();
}
```

An alternative way would be to move that check into `set_values`, where all the other checks also take place:

```
    if ($this->password_one == "" || $this->password_two == "") {
        $this->show_message("Field/s are empty");
    } else if($this->password_one != $this->password_two){
        $this->show_message("Please make sure the passwords match");
    }else if (strlen($this->password_one) <= 10) {
        $this->show_message("The password you provided is too weak");
    } else {
        $this->password_one = md5($this->password_one);
        $this->change_password_to_new();
    }
```

Note that I rearranged the if statements for more readability, and used the `shoe_message` method for all messages, instead of using echo.

**Naming**

- `is_posted` doesn't seem like an optimal name, although I have problems coming up with a better name.
- PHP class names should be in CamelCase

**Misc**

- I would not change a user password. If a user wants their password to be `"    <p>  \'  <!-- super good password -->` why not let them? In addition to annoying users, this could also lead to real problems, because you have to use those exact filter functions everywhere where the user supplies a password, as otherwise some users will not be able to login.
- in `set_values`, the `or (strlen($this->password_two) > 10` check is unnecessary, as `password_one` and `password_two` are equal and `password_one` is already checked.
- security: `md5` isn't really considered good enough anymore. If possible, you should use bcrypt (`password_hash` in PHP) or pbkdf2 instead.

Comment: then wont the is_empty method call set_values regardless?  and then set_values method try processing the empty fields? because if i do it your way set_values function is always being called

Comment: @sami7913 they way you have it, it's also called if one field is filled in, and one isn't, right? So `set_values` will be called, and then exit, because the passwords aren't equal. But I guess your right, that could be the desired functionality.

Comment: I fixed that using a simple count variable to count how many times it has looped. Anyways upvoted. It's always good to hear other people's opinions. Thanks alot!